# ADO.NET Query optimisation

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, query-optimization

I have a bit of a strange one happening. The first query I got from running a profiler on a C# ADO.NET application. What it is doing is not as interesting as the way the parameters are being passed - This query is taking 250+ seconds to complete, but when I modify it (Query 1) by changing the way the parameters are passed (see Query 2), then it takes <0.001 seconds to complete.

What is at play here? Is there anything we can do to force ADO.NET to generate a more optimal query?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Query 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    BSM.Instruments 
WHERE 
    DataBlockId=@0 AND 
    InstrumentId IN (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT InstrumentId 
        FROM 
            BSM.InstrumentPositions 
        WHERE 
            DataBlockId=@0 AND 
            PortfolioId IN (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT PortfolioId 
                FROM 
                    BSM.PortfolioLeaves(@1,@2)
            )
    )'
,N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,@2 uniqueidentifier'
,@0='B1C69A98-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'
,@1='ABADF5F7-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'
,@2='ABADFF41-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Query 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @0 uniqueidentifier = 'B1C69A98-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'
declare @1 uniqueidentifier = 'ABADF5F7-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'
declare @2 uniqueidentifier = 'ABADFF41-50D3-11DE-A173-00155DE1F500'

exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    BSM.Instruments 
WHERE 
    DataBlockId=@0 AND 
    InstrumentId IN (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT InstrumentId 
        FROM 
            BSM.InstrumentPositions 
        WHERE 
            DataBlockId=@0 AND 
            PortfolioId IN (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT PortfolioId 
                FROM 
                    BSM.PortfolioLeaves(@1,@2)
            )
    )
'
,N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,@2 uniqueidentifier'
,@0
,@1
,@2
```

Comment: your two queries are not identical (identifiers are different) -- perhaps that has something to do with how long the query takes to run?

Comment: @Jonathan - sorry to confuse the issue, have edited the post to make them the same. The parameters are not the issue (i wish they were :(  ).

Comment: Can you show the execution plans for both queries? It doesn't seem like there should be any difference in how the two queries execute.

Comment: how should I show them? I can upload the .sqlplan files somewhere, or I guess I could take a screen shot? (the two plans are vastly different, actually)

Comment: SELECT * can be a little dubious - does it make any difference if you replace * with a list of columns in both queries?

Comment: Please use  the 'sqlserver' tag rather than 'mssql'. Watch the suggestions when tagging your questions: any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong. 'mssql' is not used on any other questions.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to guarantee optimal performance is to put your query into a stored procedure.  Then use query analyzer to analyze the query plan and verify that the SQL Server optimizer is using meaningful indexes (as opposed to table scans) to retrieve the data.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

You should also get rid of the SELECT * and replace it with SELECT and the column definitions. Also using a GUID will be slower than using an int when querying data.